# Vue JS : Can not update dom from created function

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I created my project by

```
vue init webpack project
@vue/cli 4.0.5
```

Here is my App.vue.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>
```

Router file

```
let router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/videos',
      name: 'Videos',
      component: Videos
    }
  ]
})
```

Files under Videos folder

index.js

```
import Videos from './Videos'
export default Videos
```

Videos.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
     <li v-for="video in videos" :key="video.index">
      {{ video.index }} - {{ video.value }}
     </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="button">
      <cv-button @click="submit">Submit</cv-button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  created: () => {
    const _this = this
    const url = process.env.API_URL
    axios.get(url + 'api/hello', {mode: 'no-cors'})
      .then(response => {
        const resource = response.data
        const videos = resource.videos
        _this.videos = Object.keys(videos).map((key) => {
          return {
            index: key,
            value: videos[key]
          }
        })
      })
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      videos: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit: function () {
      const url = process.env.API_URL
      axios.get(url + 'api/videos')
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response)
          const resource = response.data
          const videos = resource.videos
          this.videos = Object.keys(videos).map((key) => {
            return {
              index: key,
              value: videos[key]
            }
          })
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Basically, I want to get a list of videos inside `created` function but neither `this.videos` nor `_this.videos` worked. When I tried to log `this` inside the `created` function, I was seeing a {} JSON object, not VueComponent.

```
{
  a: {computed: {}, data: f, ...},
  videos: [{...},{...}]
}
```

When I tried to get the list by click on the button, which triggers the `submit` function, it worked as expected, and `this` was a VueComponent.

```
VueComponent {_uid: 23, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: VueComponent, …}
```

I don't understand what happened here? Why I worked with the `submit` function but not inside the `created` function?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `created: () => {}`  notation created function executes in global scope. Try `created() {}`